# ¿Cómo eliminar el espacio entre este header y el nav?

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

Buenas tardes.
Estoy empezando en esto de la programación web con HTML5 y CSS3 y próximamente JS, y al hacer un intento de página web, **sin tener ninguna función actual**, tras haber hecho el header que contiene un form únicamente (y de momento), y acto seguido un nav con tres links, aparece entre éstos, un espacio en blanco como si hubiera un párrafo o un margin.

**Ahora que lo he ejecutado con el ejecutador de código, ese espacio que menciono, no aparece, pero si lo ejecuto en mi equipo local, sí que sigue apareciendo.**

Así se me muestra:

[image: resultado del html y css en el equipo local]

CSS3

```css
body   {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   font-family: Monaco, Consolas, "Lucida Console", monospace;
   background-color: #151515;
   word-wrap: break-word;
 }

/* TODO PARTE DEL HEADER */
header {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   border: 0px black solid;
   display: block;
   background-color: #005eff;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

input[type=text] {
       padding: 6px 5px;
       margin: 8px 0;
       box-sizing: border-box;
   }
input[type=password] {
       padding: 6px 5px;
      margin: 8px 0;
       box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type=submit] {
       color: white;
       padding: 7px;
       background-color: #0045ff;
       border: 1px #0045ff solid;
   }
input[type=submit]:active {
       color: white;
       padding: 7px;
       background-color: #003EE5;
      border: 1px black solid;
   }

.registro {
       color: white;
   width: auto;
   font-size: 12.3px;
   text-shadow: none;
   }

form {
    padding: 1%;
   text-align: right;
   border: 0px solid black;
}

/* TODO PARTE DEL NAV */
nav {
   height: auto;
   width: 42%;
   background-color: #005eff;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   margin: auto;  
}
nav a {
   padding-left: 2%;
   padding-right: 2%;
}

a {
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 21px;
   text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

/* TODO PARTE DEL CENTRO */
article{
   height: auto;
   width: 90%;
   margin: auto;
   margin-top: 15px;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 36px;
   color: white;
}


div#quees span#antes {
   display:block;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 36px;
   color: white;
}
div#quees:hover span#antes {
   display:none;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 36px;
   color: white;
}
div#quees span#despues {
   display:none;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 36px;
   color: white;
}
div#quees:hover span#despues {
   display:inline;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 36px;
   color: white;
}

table{
   margin-left:auto; 
       margin-right:auto;
} 


/* TODO PARTE DEL FOOTER */
footer{
   height: auto;
   width: 42%;
   text-align: center;
   margin: auto; 
   font-size: 9px;
   margin-top: 15px;
   color: white;
}

HTML
```

```html
<html>

 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Título</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>

 <body>
  <header> 
   <form>
    <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Nombre" required>
    <input type="password" name="passwd" placeholder="Contraseña" required><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión"> <a href="https://google.es" class="registro">Regístrate</a>
   </form>
  </header>
  <nav>
   <a href="#">INICIO</a> <a href="#">HISTORIA</a> <a href="#">NOTICIAS</a>
  </nav>

  <article>
   <p>
    ¿Y si... nada de lo que créemos que es real, lo es, más que serlo por ser un imperativo social?
   </p>

   <p>
    <div id="quees">
         <table border="0">
             <tr>  
                  <td><span id="antes">¿Qué es esto?</span><span id="despues">Nada de momento...</span></td>
             </tr>
         </table>
    </div>
   </p>
  </article>
  
  <footer>
   Página WEB creada por Javier Green - 2017
  </footer>
 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El formulario tiene un estilo predeterminado con el navegador que excede el alto del header. Solo tienes que agregarle un **margin-bottom: 0;**

```css
form {
      padding: 1%;
      text-align: right;
      border: 0px solid black;
      margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Ha funcionado perfectamente. Añadiendo "margin-bottom: 0;" ha solucionado el error.